# Calculating the cumulative sum in a list starting at the next element and going through the list in Python

Tags: python, list, sum

Let's say I got a list like this:

`L = [600, 200, 100, 80, 20]`

What is the most efficient way to calculate the cumulative sum starting from the next element for every element in the list.

The output of should thus be:

```
 x_1 = 400 (200 + 100 + 80 + 20)
 x_2 = 200 (100 + 80 + 20)
 x_3 = 20 (20)
 x_4 = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    l = [600, 200, 100, 80, 20]
    res = [sum(l[i:]) for i in range(1, len(l))]
    print(res)
```

for your example the output should be `[400, 200, 100, 20]`

Answer (score 0):

try using cumsum

```
L = [600, 200, 100, 80, 20]
df=pd.DataFrame(L,columns=['Value'])
df['Running_Total'] = df['Value'].cumsum()
df['Running_Total2'] = df['Value'].expanding().sum()
print(df)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the sum functio
sum(L)-L[0]

Comment: Hi pythonista, please could you elaborate as this solution won't work as is -  you'll need some kind of loop as the OP wants to output a list of sums